# i am getting No such file or directory when running react native project in android studio . hope some will help me into that

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, react-native

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/bri/project:/Users/bari/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.5-bin/6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p/gradle-6.5/lib/ant-1.10.7.jar (No such file or directory)

using
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",

Comment: did you open in android studio and do gradle sync after then clean project and rebuild project.

Comment: hi @Govind its showing the error in gradle syn , i also delete .idea .gradle and gradle folder and also done changes in gradle and gradle wrapper for different versions of gradle but did not work , also tried invalidatecache and restart did not worked

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/bri/project:/Users/bari/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.5-bin/6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p/gradle-6.5/lib/ant-1.10.7.jar (No such file or directory)

Comment: hi @GovindMaheshwari finally, i found the issue the issue was with my project location with special characters(silly mistake in project path).

changed my project location path ,
open project in android studio
then sync it and it work fine now.

i am closing the issue now